# Equivalent of CreateProcess() in C++ standard Library template (STL)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, createprocess

We know that, [CreateProcessAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) is used in C program to create a process (to launch an EXE etc..).

I tried exploring if there is any way in C++ using STL (standard library) that we can achieve the same thing.

The reason being, in CreateProcess() API we need to bother about the various types liek LPTSTR (Unicode/MBCS etc..).

But if there is any C++ STL equivalent which would abstract all these details it would be very helpful.

Comment: "STL" is just misleading here. The C++ Standard Library has grown to include bits from both the old IOstreams, string library, STL and most recently Boost libraries, plus some own inventions along the way, plus the C99 Standard Library by reference.

Answer (score 2):

No, `CreateProcess` is used in **Windows** programs. C programs use `system`. This is available in C++ as [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).

Comment: I'm just trying to understand things better. So, does it mean that system() [in C] & [std::system in C++] internally call callCreateProcess() ?

To give an analogy on what I was searching for as we have many things abstracted & easy to program in standard C++ library (std), for example (analogy) ifstead of meddling with internal characters etc.. we use string objects (which has abstracted character operation), do we have some similiar API exposed by C++ standard library which can help in creating the process()?

Comment: @codeLover: Or `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcessEx` or perhaps yet another similar function. Irrelevant details, usually. When you call `system` you get a new process by whatever means your compiler vendor considers appropriate. In case of Visual C++ that's Microsoft too, so they should know.